# mariaDB master to master replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb

I have just started using mariaDB.  I wanted to make a master to master replication.  Tried a few tutorials but all failed.

I have followed a newer tutorial in do
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04
I know that it's saying mysql group but I did heard mariabDB is super similar to mysql
The error that I had has something to do with gtid mode which I checked that the gtid value is different between mysql  and mariadb
This is the error I got
`[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'gtid_mode=ON'`

Also, followed other tutorials saying for master to master but also failed too (those posts were a bit older like a year old)

`Current maria version :10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
OS: Ubuntu  16.04
innodb: 5.6.36-82.0`

I am wondering if there's a more recent step by step tutorial to set up master to master replication?
Or is anyone able to give me a hand on how to get the process going?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*MySQL* and *MariaDB* have compatible API, which means the clients and programs should work with either MySQL or MariaDB without any changes. However on the server side they are more and more diverging and not all MySQL config options are available in MariaDB and vice versa.

In particular *MariaDB* and *MySQL* have different GTID implementations that are not compatible and have different configuration options. Here is a list of [System Variable Differences Between MariaDB 10.0 and MySQL 5.6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-variable-differences-between-mariadb-100-and-mysql-56/).

When you look up the gtid_mode parameter in the table it shows that it's not available in MariaDB and in turn links to [MariaDB and MySQL have different GTID implementations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/gtid/).

I suggest you either use the *real MySQL 5.6* for your master-master cluster or if you insist on using MariaDB better Google something like "*mariadb master-master replication*" and use a tutorial specific to MariaDB.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: been reading quite a few mariaDB tutorial...all off them are so different :|